# Changing .AndroidStudio4.0 Folder Location

Tags: android-studio

Any solutions in moving Android Studio folder named ".AndroidStudio4.0"? I want to move it somewhere that's not in my home directory.

I'm a Windows user.
Here's the photo link of the folder:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkJ7n.png